# POWERSHELL - Remove Quotation Marks from CSV for just one column

Tags: powershell, csv, quotation-marks

I want to remove the quotation marks for only the first column of my csv file with powershell

So instead of:

```
"Username","Identifier"
"booker12","9012"   
"grey07","2070"
```

I want the result to be:

```
Username,"Identifier"
booker12,"9012" 
grey07,"2070
```

To remove all quotation marks the code would be

```
Import-Csv "test.csv" | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -Replace '"', ""} | Out-File C:\CSV_Tests\test.csv -fo -en ascii
```

But how to remove the marks just for the first column?

Thanks!

Comment: The `-NoTypeInformation` parameter suggest that you using an old version of PowerShell. I recommend you install the [latest PowerShell version](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) which has an new [ConvertTo-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) with a [`-quotefields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv#-quotefields) parameter.

Comment: this is not possible, in our company we have to use an older version for several production reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, it is recommended to install the [latest PowerShell version](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) which has a new [`ConvertTo-Csv`/`Export-Csv` cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) with a [`-quotefields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv#-quotefields).
But as that appears not to be possible for your environment:

```
$Csv = @'
"Username","Identifier"
"booker12","9012"   
"grey07","2070"
'@ -Split '\r?\n'
```

```
$Csv -Replace '^"([^"]*)"', '$1'
Username,"Identifier"
booker12,"9012"
grey07,"2070"
```

**Explanation:**

1. The first `^` marks the beginning of a line
2. `([^"]*)` selects all successive characters that aren't double quotes
3. '$1' is the placeholder the results of the sequence defined in `2.`

For your file this means:

```
(Get-Content .\Test.csv) -Replace '^"([^"]*)"', '$1' |Set-Content .\Test.csv
```

- Note that the parenthesis around `(Get-Content .\Test.csv)` are not recommended but required if you write back to the same file.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. -Replace is not possible